# What is the best way to synchronize two post methods

Tags: rest, web-services, architecture, microservices, scheduler

I am developing rest service.
There are two post methods.

The first method:

```
post /something
```

1. receive the first part of data
2. save to database
3. return the answer with id
4. make async actions with data

The second method:

```
post /something/{id}/details
```

1. Receive the second part of data with id
2. Checks that first method is completed
3. process whole data

What is the best way to develop such interaction?

1. The second method checks database for the completion
2. Scheduler checks database for existence of whole data and process it
3. Another

Comment: What describes when the first part of the data is processed? If u have an identifier for the data that u are handling in the first method do u still have it in the second method?

Comment: @LukasCoomans, I have fixed description. The first method return identifier for the whole data, which the second can use

Answer (score 0):

Since you know what you are working on in the second endpoint u know which data to check in your database.

I would recommend just checking if the data exists in the database and then proceed with your logic.

if you were to schedule a task for the endpoints u are using u would be adding unnecessary state fullness to the application.

Always try to have your endpoints be as stateless as possible.

Comment: But if data not exists, wait for existense? or return response?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a event driven architecture to achieve what you wish!

Like this:

```
post /something
```

```
 1. Receive the first part of data
 2. Save to database
 3. Return the answer with id
 4. Make async actions with data
 5. Raise an event with async-something-process-done
```

The second method:

```
post /something/{id}/details
```

```
 1. Receive the second part of data with id;
 2. Checks that first method is completed (I don't know 
    man! Create a flag, attribute... whatever!);
 3. If the something was previously processed then
       process whole details data using a service, function 
       or what ever you have implemented to do this process.
    Else
       store whole details data in a temporary storage.
```

Now... In other part of your application you can add a event listener, this will listener the `async-something-process-done`, and you must implement a handler to get the id of the `something` processed and search for `something details` stored in temporary storage, if there are some details then pass the `something details` retrieved from you temporary storage to you service, function or what ever you have implemented to do this process you use in the post implementation.

This kind of architecture requires some good design to segregate responsibilities of pieces of your system (receive post, validate payload, store in db, store in temp storage, process something and process something details).

Take a look at theses refs.:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture#:~:text=Event%2Ddriven%20architecture%20(EDA),of%2C%20and%20reaction%20to%20events.&text=An%20event%2Ddriven%20system%20typically,sinks)%2C%20and%20event%20channels.

https://microservices.io/patterns/data/event-driven-architecture.html

https://www.redhat.com/en/topics/integration/what-is-event-driven-architecture

Comment: but what if the event happened, but data of something details have not been received

Comment: Depending on the complexity of your business rules, and in a scenario like this, you need to map the "compensation steps" to reverse operations, or notify the user or system, or even put this event in a retry status to try one or (X) more times to wheres it needs with **something** if the **something datails** do not arrives.

Do some researchs on Saga compensation patterns.